# is it safe to pass std::variant over the network, cross platform

Tags: c++, compatibility, std-variant

std::variant is a replacement of union.

But union can pass over network and receive in another platform(different compiler or arch) safely. Can std::variant do so?

For example, I have two machine A and B. A is windows, MSVC 19.4. B is Linux, gcc(or other compilers, such MSVC 17).
I compile the code under A(or B):

```
std::variant<int, double> v = 1; // holds int.
f.write(&v, sizeof(v));
```

Can B read correct value using the following code from the same file?

```
std::variant<int, double> v;
f.read(&v, sizeof(v));
```

If std::variant couldn't pass over network safely. Are there any library provides one? boost::variant? or maybe to create a customize implemation that act like std::variant?

Comment: You shouldn't even pass an `int` over the network like that, let alone `std::variant`. Use a serialization library or serialize it yourself.

Comment: There is actually a good question hiding inside this one: whether a variant that contains only PODs is itself a POD. Rereading the (briefly short) definition of variant, it is silent on this subject matter, so I'll say it's unspecified.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik At least in C++20 it is, don't know whether it is considered defect report against C++17. Change results from [p0602r4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0602r4.html).

Comment: @OP: Your code doesn't compile either, if `f` is a standard stream. You need to `reinterpret_cast` to `char*` explicitly to make this compile.

Answer (score 5):

In general, neither union, variant or many other types in C++ can be memory dumped into a file and then safely read.

When transferring data across multiple platforms (meaning hardware), many things can make the transfer unsafe:

- [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) (most machines today such as x86 are little endian)
- Size (the `int` type you are referring to for example can be 4 bytes on one platform, 8 on another.)
- How many bits a byte has (`CHAR_BIT`, usually 8, granted this only applies to few arcane platforms)
- The floating point implementation used. ([IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) is used by most hardware these days, but the C++ standard does not require this)

Because of this, the only *safe* way to transfer data cross-platform is to use a standardized intermediate data format, which is usually called serialization.
Many libraries can help you with this.
Some to look into are

- [Boost serialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)
- [Cereal](https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/)
- [Protobuf](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf)

If the question is more targeting the memory layout of `std::variant`, the same thing goes for `std::variant` as any other `std` container: the memory layout is implementation defined. (Implementation here means the standard library implementation used). For example, some standard library do a small string optimization in `std::string`, which can contain small strings (say, less than 32 characters) without heap allocations. Some don't. So then you have a very big difference in memory layout for the same type.

So either you guarantee that both sender and receiver have the same hardware and standard library implementation or you use a serialization library to ensure the same data arrives as what you sent.